# Reassigning STDOUT for a forked process

Tags: perl

I am trying to assign `STDOUT` of a forked process to a pipe. For example

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw(say);
use IO::Select;

my $cmd='sleep 2; echo Hello';
pipe(PREAD, PWRITE);

my $pid=fork();
if ($pid==0) {
  *STDOUT=*PWRITE;
  exec $cmd;
  die "Could not run command \"$cmd\"";
}
my $sel = IO::Select->new( \*PREAD );
say "Waiting for background process..";
while (1) {
  my @ready = $sel->can_read;
  last if (! @ready);
  for my $fh (@ready) {
    say "Processing file descriptor ".($fh->fileno());
    my $line=<$fh>;
    if (! defined $line) {
      say "EOF";
      $sel->remove($fh);
      next;
    }
    chomp($line);
    say "Got line: \"$line\"..";
  }
}
waitpid ($pid,0);
say "Done.";
```

But nothing appears in the pipe `PREAD`; the child still outputs to `STDOUT` and not to the pipe.

Comment: perl has a shortcut for that: `open my $pipe, '$cmd |'` or `open my $pipe, '-|', $cmd, @args`. See the [docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perlfunc.pod#open-FILEHANDLE-EXPR).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *STDOUT=*PWRITE;

this will only assign the perl filehandle PWRITE to the perl filehandle STDOUT, but not change the underlying file descriptor of the OS. To do this you would need to duplicate the underlying file descriptor from PWRITE to fd 1 (STDOUT):

open(STDOUT,">&PWRITE");

After you've do this PWRITE is duplicated and is now accessible as PWRITE and STDOUT. A good style is to `close(PWRITE)` then to make STDOUT the only file handle for writing into the pipe.

Comment: @hobbs: you are right, I've changed it accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Steffen, this works.. But now the `select` loop is not ending.. How can I detect EOF in the `select` loop?

Comment: PREAD will not return EOF until PWRITE is closed. And while it is closed inside the child after `exec` is done, you still keep it open in the parent process. So you need to add an explicit `close(PWRITE)` in the parent after the fork.